# Scanning A4 on a Canon Scanner

Tags: printing, printer, scanner

I have a CanonScan 9000F.
I am scanning an A4 document, and then reprinting; however, the print out that comes, is a bit smaller, in such a way that there is a small line visible at the end of the print out, clearly making obvious that this was scanned and printed out. - I am using the software ScanGear that came bundled with the scanner.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty common issue.

Scanners can scan the whole A4 sheet, however printer need some margin, so it'll decrease document's size, to fit it on the printable part of the A4 sheet.

I suppose you scan your document as pdf, at print, instead of page sizing: "fit" select "Actual size", or you may select "Custom scale" and set value manually to reach desired size.